# VSC Mac M1 Install - "required library libhostfxr.dylib could not be found"

Tags: visual-studio-code, power-platform

I just installed the Apple Silicone version of VSC. I then installed the Power Platform extension in hopes of connecting into my Power Apps Portal environment.

Per Microsoft's instructions, I tried to use a new Terminal window to enter `pac` and I received this error

```
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/Users/andrewdowning/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/microsoft-isvexptools.powerplatform-vscode/pac/tools/].

If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/etc/dotnet].
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Both VSC and the current preview version of Power Platform support M1. If you are on newer versions of macOS, Apple may have introduced errors breaking Power Platform.

The [Go64 app](https://www.stclairsoft.com/Go64/) can help verify your VSC and PAC app are m1 (arm) compatible.

Here are the supported versions:

[VSC for M1](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_54)

[Power Platform Preview Release for M1](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-platform-extension-for-vs-code/)